# PWA push server knows where to send after device restarts

Tags: javascript, web, browser, notifications, progressive-web-apps

I am currently studying PWA and bumped into a question about push API:

When push server sends browser service worker notifications, that's because the browser subscribed to the notification server with unique endpoint with a token to identify that is the particular browser to send notification to.

However, endpoint involves IP address or domain, if I subscribed to notification at home and then go to public WiFi, I still receive notification, how does the notification server know where to push to? Because what notification server stores is my previous endpoint with home WiFi IP.

Comment: the service worker phones home, somewhat like dynDNS did back in the day.

Comment: Thank you.  But like how?  None of the protocol would know where to send unless they know the exact destination.  I was thinking, the only way I could think of is that the service worker somehow restarts automatically after the computer (or network change) restarts and the service worker repeats the step of subscribing so notification server would get the newest endpoint but I could not find such step in push API lifecycle.